# How to do schema validation after a transform?

Tags: typescript, zod

Let’s say I have a schema that knows how to parse a string, and a schema for an object that string is supposed to represent. I want to parse the string into the object and validate the result.

I know I can do validation inside the transform, like this:

```js
import { z } from "zod"
export const Book = z.object({
  type: z.literal("book"),
  title: z.string(),
  published: z.number().int().min(1900)
});

export const bookFromString = z.string().transform(s => {
  const regexp = /^(.*) (\d+)$/.exec(s);
  return Book.parse({
    type: "book",
    title: regexp[1],
    published: +regexp[2]
  })
})
console.log(bookFromString.safeParse("abc 180"))
```

But this will break `safeParse`, because if the string fails to parse it will throw an exception anyway as part of the transform. Is there some other way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out that you can do this with the [`pipe`](https://zod.dev/?id=pipe) method:

```
const bookFromString2 = bookFromString.pipe(Book)
```